# Как в Python разбить видео по кадрам и сделать анимированную гифку?

Tags: python, видео, поиск-библиотек, gif

Какие библиотеки python могут помочь в решении двух разных, не связанных задач:

1. Кусок видео разбить по кадрам.
2. Сделать анимированную гифку.

Comment: И то и другое делается с помощью ffmpeg, а Python здесь не очень нужен

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Но пишут что через Python тоже можно подобраться к ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё сделал, показываю. Метод вытащен из класса, но всё понятно. 
Использовал библиотеки imageio и PIL.

```
def crop_and_anim(self):
    video = imageio.get_reader(os.path.join(self.pathTo, self.videoFile),  'ffmpeg')
    all_signs = self.parse_xml()
    for sign in all_signs:
        cropped_signs = []
        for frame in sign:
            image = video.get_data(int(frame[0])) 
            image_frame = Image.fromarray(image)
            tags = [float(tag) for tag in frame[1:5]]
            cropped = image_frame.crop(tags) 
            cropped = cropped.convert("RGB")    
            cropped_signs.append(cropped) 
        path_to_animated = os.path.join(self.pathTo, self.dir2, 'animated__%d.gif' % int(all_signs.index(sign)))
        imageio.mimsave(path_to_animated, cropped_signs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/)

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = (VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
        .subclip((1,22.65),(1,23.2))
        .resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("annimation.gif")
```